# Empty buffer shows when using emacsclient on windows

Tags: microsoft-windows, emacsclient, cygwin

I am using GNU Emacs for Windows alongside of cygwin, and I want to set my `EDITOR` shell variable to be `emacsclient -a=`.  My problem is that when certain programs try to use `EDITOR` to launch an editor with some pre-populated text, like `git commit`, `fc`, or `edit-and-execute-command` from bash, the emacs client frame opens with an empty buffer.  How do I get it to show the contents of the file that the program is trying to open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The editor shows a blank buffer because it it trying to open a file
with a cygwin styled path.  e.g. `/tmp/bash-fc.abcdef` which in turn
tries to open `C:\tmp\bash-fc.abcdef` which doesn't exist, so it opens
a new file.  The solution is to define a function which takes a path and uses 
`cygpath` to convert it to a windows path, and opens it with
`emacsclient`. I have put this in my `.bashrc` and it seems to work.

```
function emacsclientWindowsPath() { emacsclient -a= -- $(cygpath -w $1); }
export EDITOR='emacsclientWindowsPath'
```